# Como abrir uma tela de mensagem em todas as views que o usuário entrar? +Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Após logado, preciso mostrar uma mensagem (abrir uma tela de mensagem -um modal ou em uma view separada-) em todas as páginas que ele visitar. 
A mensagem só irá parar de ser mostrada quando for apertado "Não mostrar mais a mensagem". Será salvo em uma tabela essa informação para que posteriormente não seja mais mostrada essa mensagem.

A solução que fiz foi criar um ajax e verificar se na tabela ele clicou ou não em "não mostrar a mensagem". Existe uma outra maneira de fazer isso com Laravel?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link da [documentação do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#including-sub-views), acredito que seja isso o que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Visto que a ação só será disparada quando você entrar na tela, não há necessidade do request ser feito através do ajax. Você pode retornar um parâmetro no seu controller indicando que esse aceite na mensagem foi enviado.

O cálculo do parâmetro a ser enviado para as views podem ser calculados em um middleware e incluído no constructor do ApplicationController (ou nos constructors dos controllers que façam sentido).

No layout você renderiza uma partial qualquer aonde faria a inclusão do componente que exibe a mensagem e o controle para não visualizar mais, segundo o parâmetro calculado no middleware citado acima.

Resolve o problema de uma maneira clean e economiza uma request por página.

Answer (score 0):

Sem usar alguma forma de armazenamento eu acho difícil, mas acredito que não seja necessário um `ajax` para verificar isso a cada `view` carregada. Você pode acessar o atributo do user(que esteja sendo usado na tabela do user) para verificar se clicou ou não. E usar o `ajax` somente para alterar esses valores.

Exemplo:

**app.blade.php**

```
//...

@if (Auth::user()->naoMostrar == 0)
    //Modal e ações(js, ..) que o acionem
@endif

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Incluindo subvisualizações

A diretiva `@include` do Blade permite que você inclua uma **view** do Blade de dentro de outra **view**. Todas as variáveis ​​que estão disponíveis para a visualização no parent serão disponibilizadas para a visualização.

```
<div>
    @include('shared.errors')

    <form>
        <!-- Form Contents -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Mesmo que a visualização incluída herde todos os dados disponíveis na visualização pai, você também pode passar uma matriz de dados extras para a visualização incluída:

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Claro, se você tentar uma view que não existe, o **Laravel** vai lançar um erro. Se você gostaria de incluir uma view que pode ou não estar presente, você deve usar a diretiva: `@includeIf`

```
@includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Se você gostaria de incluir, dependendo de uma determinada condição booleana, você pode usar a diretiva:
`@includeWhen`

```
@includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Para incluir a primeira exibição que existe de uma determinada matriz de visualizações, você pode usar a diretiva:
`@includeFirst`

```
@includeFirst(['custom.admin', 'admin'], ['some' => 'data'])
```

Fonte: [Documentação oficial do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade)

Acredito que o approach mais apropriado seria:

```
@includeWhen(Auth::user()->mostrarMensagem, 'view.name');
```

Dessa forma você só irá incluir esta view se a variável for true